# How I can prevent fragment transition when dragging in a canvas inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a android application for rendering math graph on a canvas (plane). The plane is part of a fragment collection. So you can go from one fragment to another dragging the screen. But I want to prevent this happen when the user is in the plane fragment because in the plane the user can draw, drag, move the plane by dragging. Here is the problem because when dragging the plane fragment does the transition to the next one.

I want the transition do not happen when dragging on the plane.
Who I could avoid fragment transition when dragging in a canvas inside a fragment?

Comment: This sounds like you might need to make some adjustments to your UX. In the meantime, what do you want a user to do if they are on the PlaneFragment and want to navigate to the next fragment (not draw on it)?

Comment: There is tab on top to change the current fragment

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a viewpager to render the fragment collection. Here's a simple hack you can explore:

**Disable the viewpager swipe when you're on the PlaneFragment, allow viewpager swipe when on other fragments.**

To do this, simply override the `onPageSelected()` method of the viewpager's `addOnPageChangeListener` as shown below:

```
viewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        // PLANE_FRAGMENT_POSITION is the position of the PlaneFragment on the viewpager
        if(position == PLANE_FRAGMENT_POSITION) {
            viewPager?.setuserInputEnabled(false)
        }
        else {
            viewPager?.setuserInputEnabled(true)
        }
    }
})
```